# Basic query about CSS absolute

Tags: css, css-position

I am playing with following HTML/CSS to understand "absolute" in CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/x0rp29kx/9/

Here is the relevant part:

```
.concentric-rectangle {
    display: block;
    //position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

When "position: absolute" is commented, it shows two rows correctly, as expected. However, when it is uncommented, it combines both into one row. Why?

I experimented by adding "myrow" class to  that is parent to all  columns(col-md-3) and declaring its position to relative. I expected that after doing so if I uncomment "position: absolute" then the rendering of the two rows would not overlap. However, it still does.

What is causing them to overlap?

EDIT: I see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc3CH.png when myrow is relative and CR is absolute vs. this https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVvnY.png when both are static. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

## The theory

`position: absolute` actually positions the element relative (haha) to the innermost element that isn't `position: static` (which is the default).

Usually, you use an ancestor somewhere that has `position: relative` with nothing that changes its position (so no `top`, `bottom`, `left` or `right` property). This is identical to `position: static` (because this is what relative position is relative to) except that it creates the containing block for elements with absolute position.

[CSS2 §10.1 Definition of "containing block"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details)

The (awesome) [Learn CSS Layout](http://learnlayout.com/) tutorial has a chapter on [position](http://learnlayout.com/position.html).

## In practice

In your case, I see two rows with the following combination of positions:

```
.myrow { position: relative; }
.concentric-rectangle { position: absolute; }
```

If `.myrow` gets static positioning, then all `.concentric-rectangle` are positioned relative to the viewport, not their row.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links. I understand your last line and that is expected behavior. But, when I give myrow relative positioning, shouldn't that render concentric-rect relative to those two rows? Thus they will be at a same position within two different rows. Hence they should not overlap, but they still do. Why?

Comment: As I said, when I tried your code with `.myrow {position: relative}`, I do get the squares on two separate lines…

Comment: Strange, I see this http://i.imgur.com/N9PNj4B.png when myrow is relative and CR is absolute vs. this http://i.imgur.com/ljfKKX5.png when both are static. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

When you position something as absolute in CSS, it basically stops taking up actual space on the page. The document will stack any elements on top of each other that have the same absolute positioning. You need the 2 absolutely positioned elements to have two different absolute positions.

Edit: to clarify, this is only true if both absolutely positioned elements have the same parent. If they have different parents then they can have the same positioning but appear on different places in the page.

Comment: This is only true if all their ancestors have `static` or `inherit` as their `position` property. But if they have ancestors with other positionings, they can have the same absolute positions, but they will be in different *containing blocks*.

Comment: Yes. To clarify I was referring to elements with the exact same parent. If two elements have the same absolute positioning and different parents then of course they can live on different places in the page.

Comment: Actually, that still isn't true. If two elements have the same absolute positioning and different parents and no uncommun ancestor that creates a containing block, then they will get the exact same position in the page…